# Words of YHWH attributed to the Holy Spirit in the OT

Tags: spirit, holy

I'm studying the NT mainly right now, so my OT knowledge is not that good.

Just like some quotes in the Old Testament spoken by Yahweh are said (in the NT) to have been spoken by the Holy Spirit (Acts 28:25-27, Heb. 10:15-17), there is at least one instance where the words of YHWH in the OT are attributed to the (Holy) Spirit also in the OT.

So in other words, does anybody know which passage I am talking about? I think they are inside the same book. Just like there are NT passages attributing YHWH quotes to the Holy Spirit, I want the same thing but just inside the OT.

If you need me to clarify, let me know.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question and joining the group.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to understand how this site is different.

Comment: Yes, could you please clarify.

Comment: I tried my best (see my response). So basically 2 OT verses with the same quote, one is YHWH and the other is the Spirit. So instead of a NT quote you have (just an example!) Isaiah 1:1 saying "YHWH said XY" and in another verse "The Spirit (of the Lord) said XY". I'm sure there is 1 such case because a Catholic a few months ago showed me that in the OT (but unfortunately I didn't save the 2 verses).

Comment: The conception of a separate person called the Holy Spirit is a Christian theology that has to be read back into the Hebrew Bible. No Jewish source prior to Christianity attributed a particular quote the way you describe

Comment: Without exact words, there are places like Numbers ch11 vv25-6 and 1 Samuel ch10 v10 where the spirit of God gives men the ability to prophesy.

Comment: I'm not talking about the personhood of the Holy Spirit in this case, just two verses that attribute a quote of YHWH to the Spirit. But it's fine, I'll read the OT myself one day.

Answer (score 1):

Jews and the earliest Christians did not normally make a distinction between God (YHWH) and the Holy Spirit, so in quoting scripture they felt free to say "The Holy Spirit says," when the actual passage refers to the LORD.

Acts 28:25-27 is a paraphrase of Isaiah 6:

> 8 Then I heard the voice of the Lord saying, “Whom shall I send? Who
> will go for us?” “Here I am,” I said; “send me!” 9 And he replied: Go
> and say to this people: Listen carefully, but do not understand!...

Likewise , Hebrews 10:15-17 is a paraphrase of Jeremiah 31, in which the prophecy begins:

> 23 Thus says the Lord of hosts, the God of Israel

The writers of the NT were either Jews or disciples of Jewish Christians who made no distinction between "God" and "the Holy Spirit." For these writers, all scripture came from God - and likewise from the Holy Spirit. At this stage of the development of Christian theology, there was no need to carefully distinguish between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Let us take these one at a time:

| Acts 28:25b-27 | Quoted from Isa 6:9, 10 |
| --- | --- |
| The **Holy Spirit was right when He spoke to your fathers** through Isaiah the prophet: ‘Go to this people and say, “You will be ever hearing but never understanding; you will be ever seeing but never perceiving.” For this people’s heart has grown callous; they hardly hear with their ears, and they have closed their eyes. Otherwise they might see with their eyes, hear with their ears, understand with their hearts, and turn, and I would heal them.’ | And He replied: “Go and tell this people, ‘Be ever hearing, but never understanding; be ever seeing, but never perceiving.’ Make the hearts of this people calloused; deafen their ears and close their eyes. Otherwise they might see with their eyes, hear with their ears, understand with their hearts, and turn and be healed. |

| Heb 10:15-17 | Quoted from Jer 31:33, 34 |
| --- | --- |
| The **Holy Spirit also testifies** to us about this. First He says: “This is the covenant I will make with them after those days, declares the Lord. I will put My laws in their hearts and inscribe them on their minds.” Then He adds: “Their sins and lawless acts I will remember no more. | But this is the covenant I will make with the house of Israel after those days, declares the LORD. I will put My law in their minds and inscribe it on their hearts. And I will be their God, and they will be My people. No longer will each man teach his neighbor or his brother, saying, ‘Know the LORD,’ because they will all know Me, from the least of them to the greatest, declares the LORD. For I will forgive their iniquities and will remember their sins no more. |

The fact that the Holy Spirit is attributed as saying (or inspiring) these messages in the OT is consistent with NT teach which says:

- 2 Tim 3:16 - All Scripture is God-breathed and is useful for instruction, for conviction, for correction, and for training in righteousness
- 2 Peter 1:20, 21 - Above all, you must understand that no prophecy of Scripture comes from one’s own interpretation. 21For no such prophecy was ever brought forth by the will of man, but men spoke from God as they were carried along by the **Holy Spirit**.

There are many more examples of this in the NT such as:

- Acts 4:25 - You **spoke by the Holy Spirit** through the mouth of Your servant, our father David: ‘Why do the nations rage and the peoples plot in vain? The kings of the earth take their stand and the rulers gather together against the Lord and against His Anointed One.’ [This quotes Ps 118:22.]
- Acts 1:16 - Brothers, the Scripture had to be fulfilled which the **Holy Spirit foretold** through the mouth of David concerning Judas, who became a guide for those who arrested Jesus.

See also Acts 4:31, Luke 1:67, Acts 2:4, 19:6, 21:4, etc.

Comment: Oh now I see how this website works. Next time I'll respond here (see my answer below). I mean the OT only.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response but I mean the OT only.

For example:
Isaiah 1:1 - "YHWH says: XY"
Isaiah 30:1 - "The Spirit of the Lord says XY"

I'm sure there is 1 instance where the OT itself quotes another OT passage where the Spirit is identified as Yahweh.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: you might want to delete this answer since it is actually a comment. To do so hit "delete" in the menu located directly below the answer.